Existence of a function in a paper
I am reading a paper in mechanical engineering and found that they take for granted the existence of the following function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that

$f$ is continous with $f(0)=f(1)=0$,
The function $g(x):= f(x) + x$ has an inverse $g^{-1}(x)$ and
$g^{-1}(x) = 2f(x) + x^3$.

Note $g(0)=0, g(1)=1$.
I cannot see any reason that such a function $f(x)$ does not exist but I cannot prove that such a function exists.
Any idea?

Seems like an odd thing to assume.  Can you link to the original paper?

It's an old paper (which is not in Engligh) and it is implicitly asserted there.

If it is online, I'd still link to it.  Someone here will (most likely) be able to read the original.  As I say, it's an eccentric thing to assume and, perhaps, the context is relevant.  In any case, I don't immediately see how to construct such a function.

Is it interested especially in $[0,1]$ rather than $\mathbb R$?  You know the slope $f\prime(0)=(\sqrt3-1)/2$ and $f\prime(1)=-1/2$.  Start with a suitable function, defined at $x=n/100$ and piecewise linear between.  Calculate the difference between $g(2f(x)+x^3)$ and $x$, then tweak your $f$ at random, aiming to shrink that difference.
